# How to add a variable to a dataset and make sure it matches up properly?

Tags: qgis

I have two sets of data that I need to combine. One is a GIS set of points corresponding to the centroids of buildings, the other is a CDV table that has data about what these buildings are used for. I'd like to colour the buildings appropriately depending on this use variable.

This means both adding the bldg_use variable to the attribute table for the centroids, as well as making sure the right use gets assigned to the right building. We use 11-digit codes to name buildings, and this is present in both datasets.

What might I write to automatically check name matches?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant **CSV** table? You can right-click your layer points or polygons then access `Properties > Joins`, click the green + sign and select your csv layer as the _Join layer_ and match the _Join_ field and _Target field_ with your `bldg_use` variable. Your points or polygons layer should now contain the data from the csv.